# coalesce, nvl and CASE not working for count(*) in the subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query with CTE and I want 0 for the NULL rows.

I want to why COALESCE(tsting), NVL(tsting2) and CASE(rw_cnt) is not working? Am i missing anything?

```
with dte AS(Select store, date_id from store cross JOIN (SELECT 
(TRUNC(sysdate)-1 + (LEVEL-10)) AS DATE_ID
FROM DUAL connect by level <=( (sysdate-2)-(sysdate-10)))
store<10)

, tmp as(Select calendar_dt, str, CASE WHEN rw_cnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE rw_cnt 
END rw_cnt, COALESCE(rw_cnt, 0) tsting, NVL(rw_cnt, 0 ) tsting2
from (SELECT calendar_dt, str,  count(*) rw_cnt FROM table2 group by calendar_dt, str))

Select store, date_id, rw_cnt, case when rw_cnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE rw_cnt END testing,
tsting, tsting2 from dte LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp ON dte.date_id = tmp.calendar_dt 
AND dte.store = temp.store
order by store, date_id;
```

And I get data like below:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| STORE | DATE_ID   | RW_CNT | TESTING | TSTING | TSTING2 |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 3     | 18-OCT-20 | NULL   | 0       | NULL   | NULL    |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 3     | 19-OCT-20 | 73     | 73      | 73     | 73      |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 3     | 20-OCT-20 | 88     | 88      | 88     | 88      |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 3     | 21-OCT-20 | 63     | 63      | 63     | 63      |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 3     | 22-OCT-20 | 100    | 100     | 100    | 100     |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 3     | 23-OCT-20 | 105    | 105     | 105    | 105     |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 3     | 24-OCT-20 | 36     | 36      | 36     | 36      |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 3     | 25-OCT-20 | 3      | 3       | 3      | 3       |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4     | 18-OCT-20 | NULL   | 0       | NULL   | NULL    |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4     | 19-OCT-20 | 30     | 30      | 30     | 30      |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4     | 20-OCT-20 | 24     | 24      | 24     | 24      |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4     | 21-OCT-20 | 38     | 38      | 38     | 38      |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4     | 22-OCT-20 | 21     | 21      | 21     | 21      |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4     | 23-OCT-20 | 37     | 37      | 37     | 37      |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4     | 24-OCT-20 | 3      | 3       | 3      | 3       |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4     | 25-OCT-20 | NULL   | 0       | NULL   | NULL    |
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Any suggestion for the query optimization is welcome... :)

Comment: Your results are not possible.  The `case` expression is replacing `NULL` and `rw_cnt` is not a string.

Comment: not sure which CASE you are talking about..

Comment: your fields named testing2 , testing3 or tsting2, tsting3?

Comment: rw_cnt is a field or an alias?

Comment: @JoeTaras Apologies for the confusion. I have updated the question..

Comment: @JoeTaras rw_cnt is actually an alias that I created in the 2nd CTE with count(*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a `LEFT` join of `dte` to `tmp`, so you get `null`s for the unmatched rows.

Maybe you think that by using `COALESCE()` and `NVL()` **inside** `tmp` the final results will show `0` instead of `null`, but this is not right.
`COALESCE()` and `NVL()` are internal in `tmp` and if you select from `tmp` only then you will not get `null`s, but since you do that `LEFT` join and there are unmatched rows then the columns for these unmatched rows will be represented by `null`s.

So you have to use `COALESCE()` and/or `NVL()` in your final `SELECT` statement if you want to remove these `null`s.

Comment: This is what happens when you are doing the same things for a long time and do not take break and you common sense just disappears. LOL Thank you @forpas for catching that out..